# Is writing interfaces to aid testing a good practice?

Tags: c#

The project I work on has multiple layers and each layer's object is being used in the subsequent layer. But some of the classes do not have any interfaces and have non virtual methods. So basically I will not be able to use a mock framework to stud those classes from other layers. When I asked the developer to create an interface for the same class, so that I can mock it, he asked me why should I create an interface if I am not going to reuse it.
Is it a good practice to write interface just to improve the testability of the code?

Comment: Suppose you had to mock a sealed class, what would you have done then?

Comment: Yes. That's why repositories are very frequently complemented by an interface so a stub implementation can be injected.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel So you mean to say its ok to ask developers to add interface citing test ability as a factor right ?

Comment: @JeffMercado then I would definitely ask them to add an interface

Comment: This probably belongs over on Programmers.SE, since it's not about any given code, but about process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be loosely coupled and has good dependency management to allow you write unit-tests *easily*. If you can't write unit-tests easily, it's the first sign that your code is not well-architectured enough, and you need to refactor it. So, your motivation to change production code(in your case to add Interface) should be to make your *code better*, not just to *aid* testing. If you could do the first - you would get the second for free.

Btw, one of the main benefits of following the TDD practice is that the good architecture is enforced from the beginning: it's difficult to write untestable code, because you write tests before you write code.

So, the answer is YES, it's OK to add Interface, but it should be done for the sake of *good* architecture, not just to help you write tests for *bad* architecture.